# comparing two string same but return false

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have an session with an array result :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [code] => 16 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [code] => 17 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [code] => 20 
        [qty] => 1 
    )
)
```

I want to remove specific one item, so i wrote the code :

```
$t = "a";
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
{

     echo "Cart item code".$cart_itm["code"];
     echo "product_code".$product_code."<br/>";

    if($cart_itm["code"] === $product_code){ //item does,t exist in the list
     $t="b";
        unset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code]);

    }else{
        $t = "c";
    }

    //create a new product list for cart

}
echo "$t";
print_r($_SESSION["products"])
```

i got a result :

```
Cart item code16 product_code17
Cart item code17 product_code17
Cart item code20 product_code17
cArray ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [code] => 16 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [code] => 17 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [code] => 20 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

I dont understand why the variable wasn't b because the second array should return true ?

EDIT :

Thank you for the help , I have tried the solution but it still the unset session is still not working

```
session_start(); 
$product_code   = $_GET["pid"]; //get the product code to remove
 echo "before :";
print_r($_SESSION["products"]);
echo "<br/>";
$t="a";
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $cart_item) {
if($key === $product_code) {
    unset($_SESSION["products"][$key]);
    $t="b";

}

}
echo "after :";
print_r($_SESSION["products"]);
echo "$t";
```

but i still got results :

before :Array ( [16 ] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) [19 ] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) [18 ] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) )
after :Array ( [16 ] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) [19 ] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) [18 ] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) ) a

is it the problem with the browser cache ?

EDIT :

I finally figure it out the solution.

```
$a = "";
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $key => $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
{
    if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code) { //item does,t exist in the list
       $a = $key;
    }


}

$b = (int)$a;
unset($_SESSION["products"][$b]);
```

Comment: if you used the product code as the array key, it would make life esier for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't manage how sessions are set, this will work for you:

```
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $cart_itm) {
    if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code){ //item does,t exist in the list
        unset($_SESSION["products"][$key]);
    }
}
```

---

#### If you can modify how the sessions are set

If I was you, I'd do as Dagon has said in the comments. If you have access to the PHP that creates the session variable, you should store it like this:

```
$_SESSION['products'][PRODUCT_CODE] = array('qty' => 1);
```

Which would result in you having an array like this:

```
Array (
    [product_code] => Array (
        [qty] => 1
    ),
    [product_code] => Array (
        [qty] => 1
    ),
    [product_code] => Array (
        [qty] => 1
    )
)
```

That way, you could simply run a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $cart_item) {
    if($key === $product_code) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

As ghost stated, it would be a lot simpler to just do:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['products'][$product_code]) unset($_SESSION['products'][$product_code);
```

Or

```
if(array_key_exists($product_code, $_SESSION['products'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['products'][$product_code]);
}
```

<sup>*Function References: [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) & [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset).*</sup>

Comment: actually a much shorter approach would be just check if `isset` or `array_key_exists` if it will be based on the key since they are already the codes, no need to loop each entry and break. but if not, then you need to loop each to look inside the array each batch

Comment: Touche @Ghost, completely forgot it's that simple. Need my morning coffee :$

Comment: but we don't know if the OP is okay with that change though, we'll see, if not this answer should suffice since the unsetting should be done using the `$key` of the `foreach`, not the `$product_code`

Comment: yeah, we have one of those once in a while. coffee should be enough :D

Comment: I think more like vodka @Ghost ;P

Comment: thank you very much for the help. I have tried the solution that provided but i don't know why after the code run,and come back to another page which show the session list and the list is still there. it was not unset. i have tried many solution i changed from the set of the session many times.this is the code that i set the session http://justpaste.it/j3rw it took me 4 hours more to figure this out. .

Comment: @Brianlee Change `if($cart_itm['code'] === $product_code)` to `if($cart_itm['code'] == $product_code)` (`==` instead of `===`) because you only want to compare the values, not the variable type as well.

Comment: @Darren i finally found out why, my last code was like this 
$a = "";
  foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $key => $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code) { //item does,t exist in the list
           $a = $key;
        }
       
       
    }
 // unset($_SESSION["products"][$key1]);
    $b = (int)$a;
    unset($_SESSION["products"][$b]); Thank you very much for your help. you made my day

Comment: Pleasure mate :) @Brianlee

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reason why the variable isn't `b` is because you set the variable back to `c` in the `else` branch.

That is to say, even though the variable IS set to `b` at some point, your loop continues to run (on to the third iteration, upon which `$cart_itm["code"]` is now `20`) and the `else` branch is evaluated, setting your variable back to `c`.

Secondly, you are unsetting the wrong thing - `$product_code` is not the correct index to use.

```
$t = "a";
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $key => $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
{

     echo "Cart item code".$cart_itm["code"];
     echo "product_code".$product_code."<br/>";

    if ($cart_itm["code"] === $product_code) { //item does,t exist in the list
        $t = "b";
        unset($_SESSION["products"][$key]);
    }

    //create a new product list for cart

}

echo "$t";
print_r($_SESSION["products"]);
```

You should get:

```
Cart item code16 product_code17
Cart item code17 product_code17
Cart item code20 product_code17
aArray ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [code] => 16 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [code] => 20 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
)
```